# Influence line question for calculating maximum bending moment

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

I have the following question:

[image]

I have no trouble drawing the influence line but I have problems with finding the magnitude. Can someone please explain how to get $\frac{8}{3}$? How should I use the unit relative rotation to find the height of the triangles?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is to investigate the moment at an internal point due to the influence of the unit load "1". The solution is illustrated below.

[image]

You shall repeat the steps to obtain the coefficient at "E".

Comment: Hi r13 thanks for the help. But why is my diagram (lecturer's solution) showing $\frac{8}{3}$? But your third diagram is showing a unit load? Can you explain the third diagram again and about imposing a unit rotation at the location? Many thanks!

Comment: I've shown two methods to construct the influence line about a point that is subjected to a concentrated load (unit load).  The first method consists of 4 steps - 1) place the unit load at the point in question, 2) calculate support reactions due to the unit load, Now disconnect the beam at the joint, then 3)  for structure left of the point, use the reaction to calculate the internal moment at the point, and 4) obtain the moment coefficient at the tip of the cantilever by the similar triangle method. My third graph represents steps 3 and 4.

Comment: What I didn't show is to finish the diagram by repeating steps 3 and 4 for the structure to the right of the point. Once you complete the task, the coefficients should be identical to your lecture note  (-4, 8/3, -8/3).

Comment: I've eliminated the second method (previously the last diagram) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi r13 thanks for the comments, what do you mean by the coefficients of the free end? I think my lecturer is using this method (method 2)

Comment: The free ends are points "A" & "E".

Comment: Hmm, can you please explain the second method just a bit more? I think I understand the first one now. I think second method is better as I don't need to calculate the reactions which gets complicated with 2 or more supports.

Comment: The second method is much simple - break the beam at point "C", and place a unit moment at the cut (Mc = 1), then get the coefficients for the points of "A" and "E" by the similar triangle method. But, didn't you start with the question about how the coefficient 8/3 at "C" was derived?

Comment: The trick, imagine using your fingers to hold the beam at "C" after the cut, then lift the ends up 1 imaginary unit, now what value do you get for "A" and "E"? A simple trig, right?

Comment: You are correct. The second method is most useful for predicting the influence of the unit load at a point of interest on a continuous beam over multiple supports.

Comment: Hi r13 thanks I think I get the similar triangles part and Obtained $M_{A}, = \frac{3}{2}$ and $M_{E} =1$, you said something about direct proportion to method 1? But ho do you get $\frac{8}{3}$ in the first place? Can you just explain slightly more, I am nearly there? How do I continue from here to get $\frac{8}{3}$

Comment: For example in this problem https://imgur.com/wG9Ow0w , I need to use method 2 to get my magnitude, here we have 3 reactions. I have drawn the influence line https://imgur.com/QbE34Y5

Comment: If you need the magnitude of the influence coefficient, you have no choice but to use the first method. Method 2 can't provide the magnitude of influence but offers a quick realization of the influence shape, and is best used to position the load on a continuous structure, usually the bridge. For now, I suggest sticking to method 1. Do you realize the linked structure is statically determinant?